# Check any missing days record in Bigquery PartitionTable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Bigquery table with a date partition key.
I get daily records in that table and I try to find if there's any missing day for like 3 years of historical data.
So I tried to use the following query:

```
SELECT KeyPartitionDate
FROM (
  SELECT KeyPartitionDate, DATE(KeyPartitionDate) as day, DATE_ADD(date(KeyPartitionDate), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS dayplusone
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE DATE_DIFF(day, dayplusone , DAY) > 1
GROUP BY KeyPartitionDate
ORDER BY KeyPartitionDate
```

The query is valid but returns no results while I know there are some...
My guess is that I'm messing with the DATE_ADD function but cant tell how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and just gives you the list of missing days

```
#standardSQL
SELECT day AS missing_days 
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(KeyPartitionDate) min_day, MAX(KeyPartitionDate) max_day
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_day, max_day)) day
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT KeyPartitionDate AS day
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
) t 
USING(day)
WHERE t.day IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You went about this the wrong way:

```
day = DATE(KeyPartitionDate)
```

then you did

```
dayplusone  = DATE_ADD(date(KeyPartitionDate), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

which is basically saying dayplusone = day +(1 day)

Then you do :

```
WHERE DATE_DIFF(day, dayplusone , DAY) > 1
```

which is like saying : dayplusone - day > (1 day) which would mean

```
day + (1 day) - day > (1 day)
```

You can clearly see why that is wrong.

What you needed to do instead is compare the current row date with the preivous row date. That is achieved using window functions:

```
SELECT KeyPartitionDate FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT KeyPartitionDate,
  LAG(KeyPartitionDate)
    OVER (ORDER BY KeyPartitionDate ASC) AS PreviousKeyPartitionDate
FROM `project.dataset.table`) 
WHERE DATE_DIFF(DATE(PreviousKeyPartitionDate),DATE(KeyPartitionDate), DAY ) > 1
ORDER BY KeyPartitionDate
```

Comment: Oh wow yes, looking that way it is much clearer ! Thanks a lot for the answer.